# Speed Up Grails Bulk Save of Complex Domain Class Structure

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class model consisting of hierarchical structure of 1:n associations, e.g.

- set (has many corrections)

  - correction (has many rows)

    - row (has many cells)

      - cell

The 1:n relations are realised with hasMany and belongsTo mappings in the domain classes. The domain instances are created from uploaded files and in the some cases one correction can consist of 20.000 rows with 20 cells for each row.

Currently the uploaded file get parsed, the domain objects are created, but not saved at this point, because the instances must be validated and the error messages displayed. If all instances are error free, I save the top-level domain class like:

```
set.save()
```

This saves the set and all associated domain instances over all levels. Now everything is managed by GORM. For huge structures the save process tends to get very slow, because most probably the hibernate session gets bigger.

I do not wanna save the instances immediately, because the validation errors should be summarized and displayed to the user. So I can not flush the hibernate session every 100 record.

Performance tests show that it takes 5:01 minutes for 8906 rows with 13 cells for each row = 115.778 records.

Environment:

- Grails 3.1.8
- Mysql DB 5.7

Are there suggestions to speed up the save procedure?

Comment: Your runtime-problem is not related to grails/gorm/hibernate. Even if you would use plain jdbc with transactions you will run into this problem if you don't commit your work every x (e.g. 100) records. In my opinion, you have to find a workaround. Maybe use an error-marker or delete the records afterwards in case of an error etc. ...

Comment: the complex data structures are not really fast-batch friendly. face it

Comment: @injecteer your are completely right, the structure is not very batch friendly, but currently no time for refactoring. After performing several tests with none cascade, hibernate stateless session, gorm flush after certain inserts, .. it turned out the the approach with cascading associations (with hasMany, belongsTo) is the fastest, what was very surprising.